# Groovy HTTPBuilder for api.github.com using OAuth

Tags: github, groovy, oauth, httpbuilder

Good day!
I generated a special Personal access tokens on github. I want to search some code into private repositories. When I use curl all works fine:

```
curl  -H 'Authorization: token <MY_PERSONAL_TOKEN>' -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.text-match+json' https://api.github.com/search/code?q=FieldDescriptionResponseChecker+@MY_PRIVATE_REPO&sort=stars&order=desc;
```

However when I try to use groovy HTTPBuilder

```
class GithubSearchService {

    private String authToken


    public GithubSearchService(String authToken) {
        this.authToken = authToken
    }


    public void search(String query) {
        def http = new HTTPBuilder('https://api.github.com')

        http.request( GET, TEXT) { req ->
            uri.path = '/search/code'
            uri.query = [ q: query]
            headers.'Authorization' = "token $authToken"
            headers.'Accept' = 'application/vnd.github.v3.text-match+json'

            response.success = { resp, reader ->
                println "Got response: ${resp.statusLine}"
                println "Content-Type: ${resp.headers.'Content-Type'}"
                println reader.text
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have 403-Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException: Forbidden
at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.defaultFailureHandler(HTTPBuilder.java:642)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
......
```

Could you help, please, make groovy work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not adding required header: `User-Agent`, see the [docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required) (FYI `curl` adds this header automatically - run it with `-v` switch). Also remember to always add *failure* handler when using `HTTPBuilder` - all the necessary info was passed there.

Here's the code:

```
@Grab('org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1')

import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.*

class GithubSearchService {

    private String authToken

    public GithubSearchService(String authToken) {
        this.authToken = authToken
    }

    public void search(String query) {
        def http = new HTTPBuilder('https://api.github.com')

        http.request(GET, JSON) { req ->
            uri.path = '/search/code'
            uri.query = [ q: 'FieldDescriptionResponseChecker+@<REPOSITORY>']
            headers.'Authorization' = "token $authToken"
            headers.'Accept' = 'application/vnd.github.v3.text-match+json'
            headers.'User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0'
            response.success = { resp, json ->
                println "Got response: ${resp.statusLine}"
                println "Content-Type: ${resp.headers.'Content-Type'}"
                println json
            }
            response.failure = { resp, json ->
                print json
            }
        }
    }
}

new GithubSearchService('<TOKEN>').search()
```